# Local rings at rational points of a group scheme are all isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be a $k$-group scheme where $k$ is a field, $g\in G(k)$ a rational point, and $\gamma (g): G(k)\to G(k)$ the translation map, which is a group isomorphism. In Demazure "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups", p. 200, it is said: "... it follows ... that the local rings of $G$ at its rational points are all isomorphic". I don't understand why.

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism and $f(x)=y$, then the local rings at $x,y$ are isomorphic. In your case, thus all local rings of interest are isomorphic to the local ring at $e$, the identity.

Comment: What I do not understand is why I have an isomorphism of schemes, and not only of (abstract) groups (of rational points). That is, why I have a morphism $G \to G$ and not only $G(k)\to G(k)$. Maybe some use of Yoneda?

Comment: But you don't have an isomorphism of abstract groups, as the translation map is not a homomorphism. It is an isomorphisms of schemes though, by the definition of group scheme.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the mistake. What I still do not understand is why you have a morphism of k-schemes $G \to G$, that is $G(T)\to G(T)$ for any $k$-scheme $T$ and not only for $T$=Spec $k$.

Comment: You interpret translation. One has a morphism (multiplication) $G\times_k G\to G$. One has a closed subscheme $G\times_k \{g\}\subset G\times G$ and thus get a morphism $G\times_k \{g\}\to G$ called translation and since $g$ is $k$-rational, $G\times_k \{g\}=G$.